# Functions in controllers and blade - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm slowly starting to come to grip with Laravel but keep having little issues doing basic things.

So this is what I have at the moment

A function and a function that is called by my `route` both in my `webcontroller.php`

```
// Function for printing out copyright year
function copyright_info($begin_year = NULL)
{
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
    if(empty($begin_year) || $begin_year == date('Y'))
        echo date('Y');
    else
        echo $begin_year." - ".date('Y');    
}

// function being called by route.php to get Restaurant Page
public function restaurant () {
    $cookie = Cookie::get("basket");
    return view('pages.restaurant', ['basket' => $cookie]);
}
```

Now all the first function does is print out something like `2013-2015` once the year is provided.

So I should be able to do something like this

```
public function restaurant () {

    // use the function and get copyright year
    $year = copyright_info('2013')

    $cookie = Cookie::get("basket");
    // pass data to the view including the year we just created
    return view('pages.restaurant', ['basket' => $cookie, 'year' => $year]);
}
```

Now in my `restaurant.blade.php` file, I'm including my footer in my `includes` folder that is generic to all my pages like this `@include('includes.footer')`. Now the footer is what actually contains a `div` that requires the `$year` I have passed to the `restaurant` view. in my `footer.blade.php` I have this

```
<p style="font-size: 0.9rem">Copyright &copy; {{ $year }}  &#124;  xxx.com Limited</p>
```

Now I would assume that when I pass data to `restaurant` and `footer` is included in `restaurant` the data will apply to `footer` when it gets included in `restaurant` but that doesn't happpen.

---

After a lot of testing, I have now found out that my function doesn't produce any data at all. This is not because the function doesn't work also because in normal `PHP` it does

Any guidance appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass $year from restaurant.blade to footer.blade

```
@include('includes.footer', ['year'=>$year])
```

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out.

1. Laravel will add the variable regardless of whether it is used in the main view or the include
2. Always, always make sure that your functions `return` something. From the question you can see that my `function` uses `echo`

Hope this helps someone in the future.